# Deactivate previous tiles

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to deactivate previous tiles when zooming in/out.
Currently the map loads all of the tiles and keeps the old ones there (scaled up) until the whole loading is completed, I could not find any setting to modify this case;
So I'm wondering how can I do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you set `zoomAnimation` to be `false` on your `Map` object? I've never used this setting myself, but I've always assumed it would turn off the behaviour you don't want.

Comment: This setting only disables the grid while zooming. When the zooming is completed, both (old and new) layers are activated back.